# How to reprioritize config.assets.paths in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, asset-pipeline

You can do for instance:

```
config.assets.paths << "#{Rails.root}/some_directory_here"
```

To add an asset path, however this puts it at the bottom.

Is there a way to add to the top or to change the order of the paths?

Some of the gems I'm using are adding their own paths and I would like to be able to override or mask their assets.

Answer (score 1):

Try to add on the top:

```
config.assets.paths.unshift("#{Rails.root}/some_directory_here")
```

Comment: +1 for the suggestion. That was the first thing I tried. Here's what happens. Say 1,2 are from the gems and 3,4 is from the app itself. You can use unshift when you add the 4th to has this order `1,2,4,3`. I'm trying to find a way to add it before 1,2 if that makes sense.

Comment: so how many paths do you need to add from your app? does it matter in which order you add them (paths from your app)? how about adding them in the reversed order then?

Comment: Well what I'm trying to do is add a path before the paths my gems are adding, that's what I can't figure out how to do. From the example above I'm trying to do "3,4,1,2" if that makes sense.

Comment: then try to reverse them and then add one by one in a loop (in the reversed order).

Comment: The problem is, going back to the example, the gem files are adding "1,2". Anything I add in the environments config gets added after that. I've even tried doing `config.assets.paths.reverse!` after adding 3 and 4, and all it only reverses the  asset paths i've added locally (1,2,4,3) instead of what I want which is (4,3,2,1) :(

Comment: You can go to github rails/rails and ask them, they should know.